# How to use existing scheduled email function programmatically in extensions?

Tags: civimail, email, gsoc, mailing

I need to send payment page links to user on schedule basis, is there any way to use existing  scheduled email functionality trough custom extension?

Comment: Hi Tahir. Can you clarify how Scheduled Reminders do not currently meet your needs.

Comment: I have created payment processing links for partial payments where when user pay first installment of partial payment then he/she will receive links of reminders or scheduled installments payment processing page link on scheduled dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an API in order to use schedule jobs

look for table called civicrm_job and make an similar entry for the newly created API and this will create an entry in schedule jobs

you can create an Extension first and then API in the Extension find the below link http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

if you need more help please let me know

Comment: Please differentiate civicrm_job and civicrm_mailing_job as I need to send emails on scheduled dates.

Comment: I haven't used civicrm_mailing_job but civicrm_job are like schedule which can be run by Corn jobs every hour / day / month / year - based on our setting -